# Setup Requires .NET Framework Version 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, installation, setup-deployment

I have a C# Winforms application I'm looking to deploy on an XP Laptop with the .NET Framework 1.1 installed.

The solution contains three projects, all with a target framework of .NET Framework 2.0

The setup project has the preqrequisite of .NET Framework 2.0 checked. No other prerequisites are checked.

Why, when I try to run the setup on the laptop, does it require me to install the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1?

(FYI I am developing in VS2008 on a machine with .NET Framework 3.5 SP1)

Thanks in advance,

Jim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it applies to you, but see the answer from PhilWilson here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/ca822298-8371-4e04-8763-cccd4615ab84

Comment: Yup, that go it. It was basically in my setup project, under Launch Conditions, the wrong version of the .NET Framework was required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do any of your projects depend on anything else other than the .NET framework? If you have a reference to something that does, then that will require its prerequisites are installed too.

I'd also triple check that you've not got one of your projects still pointing at 3.5.